# Copy and Paste with criteria VBA or Filter

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

My name is Pedro and I am very beginner in VBA development. I have a question about copy and paste with criteria. I have code that reports to me an error `1004` workbooks open when I run a macro that copy and paste row in another workbooks. How can I fix this error with the following code?

```
    Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    For i = 2 To LastRow
     'If Cells(i, 9) = "Aline" Then
        'Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 16)).Select
        'Selection.Copy

        'Workbooks.Open Filename:="L:\Controle\Assessoria Tecnica\Pessoas\Aline.xlsx"
        'Worksheets("Plan1").Select
        'erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

        'ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
        'ActiveSheet.Paste
        'ActiveWorkbook.Save
        'ActiveWorkbook.Close
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True '
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    MsgBox "Informações inseridas com sucesso", vbInformation
End sub
```

I also want to explain what my code do it. My code matches a specific condition in "I" column (like Aline, Carol, Karine, Lucas, Thiago) and after that it copies each row and pastes it in another workbook, according to the matched conditions in "I" column. So what do you think would be the problem in this situation? What can i do to fix the error? Or make a new code that copy a row with condition and paste it in another workbooks?

Comment: Your Dim is interesting.  `Dim LastRow, i, erow As Integer`

Answer (score 0):

As for your posted code, you've commented your IF block but not the entire thing.  The END IF should also be commented.

I've done similar things in the past, so let me offer some code snippets as advice.  This should get you started.  This is by no means the right or perfect way to do things, but it is simple to understand.  After years and years of writing VB, I wouldn't write it this way.  :)

```
    Sub Open_SlaveWB()
        vFile = Workbooks.Open Filename:="L:\Controle\Assessoria Tecnica\Pessoas\Aline.xlsx"
        If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
        Set UpdateSheet = wbMaster.Sheets("Update") 'Name of the sheet in the master WB to copy into
        Set wbSlave = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
        Set SlaveSheet = wbSlave.Sheets("Plan1") 'Name of the sheet in the slave WB to copy from

        Exit Sub
    errMessage:
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
        Resume Next
    End Sub
```

If you're absolutely sure the path and file name will go unchanged use this, otherwise I would advise setting vfile to: `Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsx", 1, "Select One File To Open", , False)` which will open a file select dialog box.

I've found it more efficient to copy the sheet, to your master workbook, and get the data from there rather than subsequent slave workbooks.

```
Sub Copy_SlaveToMaster()
    LastSlaveRow = SlaveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    LastSlaveColumn = SlaveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    SlaveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastSlaveRow, LastSlaveColumn)).Copy
    UpdateSheet.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial

    Exit Sub
errMessage:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

You obviously don't need the slave WB to stay open.

```
Sub Close_SlaveWB()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbSlave.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Exit Sub
errMessage:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

From there you would just write some code to manipulate the new sheet, use the data from the new sheet as you wish.